# OpenContrail Collector and Zookepper - Daemons stuck in initialization

Tags: openstack

I have a problem with OpenContrail. I do not understand why, but when I run:

```
---code_being---
root# watch contrail-status
---code_end---
```

I get a lot of daemons showing that they are stuck in initializing state. I try to stop and restart these daemons, but to know avail. I also have looked into the ZooKeeper status, but do not know how to get it back up. Any thoughts?

Here is the Contrail-Status Output:

> Every 2.0s: contrail-status                                           Mon Jul 30 20:19:24 2018
>
> == Contrail Control ==
>   supervisor-control:           active
>   contrail-control              initializing (Number of connections:4, Expected:5 Missing: IFMap
>   :IFMapServer)
>   contrail-control-nodemgr      initializing (Collector connection down)
>   contrail-dns                  active
>   contrail-named                active
>
> == Contrail Analytics ==
>   supervisor-analytics:         active
>   contrail-alarm-gen            initializing (Collector, Zookeeper:Zookeeper[Connection time-out
>   ] connection down)
>   contrail-analytics-api        initializing (Collector, UvePartitions:UVE-Aggregation[Partition
>   s:0] connection down)
>   contrail-analytics-nodemgr    initializing (Collector connection down)
>   contrail-collector            initializing
>   contrail-query-engine         initializing (Collector connection down)
>   contrail-snmp-collector       initializing (Collector, Zookeeper:Zookeeper[Connection time-out
>   ] connection down)
>   contrail-topology             initializing (Collector, Zookeeper:Zookeeper[Connection time-out
>   ] connection down)
>
> == Contrail Config ==
>   supervisor-config:            active
>   unix:///var/run/supervisord_config.sockno
>
> == Contrail Database ==
>   contrail-database:            inactive (disabled on boot)
>
> == Contrail Supervisor Database ==
>   supervisor-database:          active
>   contrail-database             active
>   contrail-database-nodemgr     active
>   kafka                         initializing

For Cassandra and ZooKeeper service I get a Blank return:

> root@ntw02:~# contrail-cassandra-status
>
> root@ntw02:~# service contrail-control status
>   contrail-control                 RUNNING    pid 21499, uptime 5:05:39
>
> root@ntw02:~# service contrail-collector status
>   contrail-collector               RUNNING    pid 1132, uptime 17 days, 5:45:34

Interesting, I restarted the contrail-collector, but the uptime does not match 07/28/2018

I am going to try and kill the process and provide the output and restart.

Comment: Still no success, the services are still stuck in initializing, I did manage to find out thought that Zookeeper wasn't running.

Comment: Had to run the zookeeper server script to start the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long awaited time-frame I finally found the answer to this question. Apparently contrail has a script that will clean up entries specifically related to the database.

Enter:

```
db_manage.py
```

You should be able to execute it with

```
python /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vnc_cfg_api_server/db_manage.py
```